# ReactJS - Fetching Within a Function

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I have a function which needs to submit an API request, wait for the response and return whether the status of the response was within the 200-299 range (i.e., the `response.isOk attribute`).

However, when I call the function from a component, I assume I get the response too late (the function doesn't wait for the fetch to finish and instead returns `undefined`). Is there a way around this?

**AuthFunctions.js**

```
export function validateToken(token) {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
    },
  };

  return fetch("/api/validateToken", requestOptions).then(
    (response) => response.ok
  );
}
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        {!token ||
        (token === "" && token === undefined) ||
        !validateToken(token) ? (
          <AuthPage setToken={setToken} />
        ) : (
          <>
            <Routes>
              <Route
                exact
                path="/dashboard"
                element={<Dashboard token={token} />}
              ></Route>
            </Routes>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: Use the `useEffect` hook to make the call and store the result in a state by using the `useState` hook. Make your component render a loading indicator of some kind until the result exists in the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your validateToken function as an asynchronous function by adding the async keyword:

(also it is not mandatory since you didn't use await as it was pointed out in the comments).

```
export async function validateToken(token) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        },
    };
    const response = await fetch('/api/validateToken', requestOptions);
    return response.ok;
}
```

You can save the token validation status in the state and use effect to call you api on the first render.

I added a hasFetched state to avoid showing the authentification page while waiting for the api response for a better user experience. I only return a loading paragraph but what you want to return is up to you.

```
function App() {

      const [hasFetched, setHasFetched] = useState(false);
      const [isTokenValid, setIsTokenValid] = useState(false)
        
      useEffect(()=>{
        validateToken(token).then((response)=>{
            setIsTokenValid(response);
            setHasFetched(true);
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error)
            setHasFetched(true);
        })
      },[])
    
    if (!hasFetched) return <p>Loading</p>;
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          {!token ||
          (token === "" && token === undefined) ||
          !isTokenValid ? (
            <AuthPage setToken={setToken} />
          ) : (
            <>
              <Routes>
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/dashboard"
                  element={<Dashboard token={token} />}
                ></Route>
              </Routes>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Making the function `async` is pointless when there is no `await` inside the function body. It's already returning a promise so it makes no difference. Alternatively, if the function is made `async`, then the promise should be awaited instead of returned, i.e: `return (await fetch("/api/validateToken", requestOptions)).ok;`

Comment: Thanks, good catch, I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From where you get the token?

Anyways, two main things you can do:

- create a isTokenValid Boolean using use state:

```
[isTokenValid, setIsTokenValid] = useState(false):
```

- create a useEffectHook that will do the validation once the app component renders/ token is changing

```
useEffect(async ()=> {
if(!!token) {
const isValid = await validateToken(token);
setIsTokenValid(isValid);
};
}, [token]);
```

Hope I helped ^^